# How to capture IIS Request Wait Time

Tags: iis, azure, azure-web-roles

Is there any way by which I can get the value of how long a request waited in the IIS queues before it was given to my Azure Web Role?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for really doesn't have anything to do with Azure since the IIS request queue is completely independent of anything in Azure - you just happen to be running IIS in an Azure VM.

For information about how to monitor request processing time see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972959.aspx.  There is a lot information in that article, but in particular you are probably interested in the `ASP.NET\Request Wait Time` counter.